# Two out of Three MovieClip buttons work in a Frame Actions using ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6

So here's the issue:

I have created 3 button symbols and they are each in their own 3 movieclip symbols with their own instance names.

In an actionframe on Frame 1, I have the following code:

```
stop();

codebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onReleaseCode);
titlebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onReleaseTitle);
audiencebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onReleaseAudience);

function onReleaseCode(e:MouseEvent):void {
 nextFrame();
}

function onReleaseTitle(e:MouseEvent):void {
 this.gotoAndPlay(187)
}

function onReleaseAudience(e:MouseEvent):void {
 this.gotoAndPlay(416)
}
```

Like I said, 2 of them work: the *audiencebutton* and *codebutton*. *titlebutton* does not.

I'm not really experienced in ActionScript 3.0, if anyone can give some input that would be great.

It couldn't be bugging because I don't use labels, does it?

Comment: As a first test, slap a trace statement on the actions layer at frame #187, and check if it actually does anything.

Comment: If you don't mind me, I'm going to edit all your emoticons and lol's out of it because they are annoying me.

Comment: sorry, it just doesn't move from Frame 1 where the button is located.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since I've been doing this kind of stuff in the past weeks, I can at least list up what needs to be checked, in case something went wrong there. Ofcourse it would be more efficient if you posted some code or told us what 'doesn't work'. Or rather, what still does work.

Anyway, make sure that:

1. Your buttons are declared correctly. Does titlebutton link to a class, which is the document class of a sprite? Make sure by editing the class of the sprite to see if you actually end up in the correct class.
2. Doublecheck that the position 187 exists on the timeline of your animation/sprite/tween. Sometimes, I tend to actually delete some positions by deleting empty Symbols.
3. Your function actually gets called. Throw in `trace`-functions everywhere. It looks cool and if you show it to someone, it actually looks like the Matrix and stuff. Plus it helps you keeping track of stuff that goes on in your application.

Comment: +1 for trace advices. And yes, debugging timeline code is an art :(

Comment: @Joetjah the button doesn't work, it does nothing. the other to work, they go to the respective frames as coded in the functions.

Comment: So, does `onReleaseTitle` get called but the sprite doesn't move to the correct frame? Or does `onReleaseTitle` not get called at all? You have to be more clear explaining than just saying 'the button doesn't work'...